# sudo select auth method (password vs fingerprint)

Tags: command-line, sudo, fingerprint-reader

In **Ubuntu 20.04**, after activating and enrolling my **fingerprint** in Applications menu ->Users  and after enabling the fingerprint in terminal using

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

and checking the fingerprint line, **how do I select password auth method when using `sudo` without having to wait a timeout**?

```
XXXXX@windows-xp:~$ sudo ls
Swipe your finger across the fingerprint reader
Verification timed out
[sudo] password for XXXXX:
```

Comment: It sounds like something is not working correctly.   Some coming here might find a helpful answer in your question: `sudo pam-auth-update` is useful along with `fprintd-enroll` for setting things up, or for dealing with re-setting things up after the bugfix that came out in June 2021.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using fprint version 1.92 or greater than you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop trying to use the fingerprint and switch to authentication via password: [commit that implemented this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/fprintd/-/commit/657f58fd648e35417ce7266b9c1558ce497dc179).